# Uses of Aspects in SQLite Databases for Android Programming in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I've written an Application that makes use of the SQLite Databases that come as part of the Android SDK, and they are all fully functioning and working correctly.

However, I'm not overly sure of what each aspect of the database code is used for, and I'd like to know for greater understanding for when I move onto projects that are larger than this one (my first android project).

Here are the parts that I'm not sure what exactly they do:

- Helper
- Context
- execSQL
- "Database Version"

I know how they are used, I just don't know how to explain what they do and how exactly? One of those things!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html might help

but basically:

Helper Class - This class contains methods such as onCreate which you will most likely need, so you can override these methods

Context - its the context of current state of the application, so when you create a new object you can use it to get information about other parts of your program

execSQL - used to run an SQL statement on your database
          myDB.execSQL("Insert into " + TABLE + " VALUES (1,0)");

Database Version - You can use this to check if the database is up to date, and if not update it using an onUpdate method